# Faith in Civilization 5: Campaign Edition (macOS)

Tags: civilization-5, macos

I have the `Civilization V: Campaign Edition` for macOS. At a point (I think playing the scenarios of the game) I remember seeing Faith and religions. Though, I cannot find that in a set-up game.

I looked a bit online, but it seems that I cannot find a clear guidance or answer for Faith in `Civilization V: Campaign Edition` for macOS. Can somebody tell me how to have Faith in the set-up games in `Civilization V: Campaign Edition` for macOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Since you are using the Campaign Edition, you will not be able to access faith or religion, as these features were added in the game's first expansion, [Gods & Kings](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Civilization_V:_Gods_%26_Kings).

[Faith](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Faith_(Civ5)) is effectively a new resource introduced in Gods & Kings used to track and make purchases for a civilization's [religion](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Religion_(Civ5)).

The Campaign Edition of the game unfortunately [does not currently have access to the game's expansions](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/civ-5-campaign-edition-on-mac-app-store.426046/) (see comments from developer AspyrRyan). Although the edition's developers have been keen to introduce these expansions to the Campaign Edition [since at least 2011](https://www.macgasm.net/news/mac-app-store/civilization-updated-crossplatform-gameplay-dlc/) at this point it is unlikely the expansions will be added, since it is now 2020 and there have been multiple Civilization games released since.

If you want to introduce Faith to your games you will have to purchase a copy of Civilization V and the Gods & Kings expansion through Steam or another platform which supports the base game and the expansion pack on Mac.